# How do I get the instagram hashtag video thumbnail from facebook api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram

I am using facebook's api for instagram and I am able to query a hashtag feed by using the permissions manage_pages and instagram_basic and calling this in the facebook graph api .

```
17842314694065016/recent_media?fields=caption,comments_count,permalink,like_count,media_type,id,children{media_type,media_url},media_url&user_id=17841400646076739
```

And I get a response like this.

```
"caption": "You're going to love this one  Share with your friends 
  Credit to samcorgi",
  "comments_count": 1,
  "permalink": "https://www.instagram.com/p/B1ZPktWBah0/",
  "like_count": 6,
  "media_type": "VIDEO",
  "id": "17850934621537158",
  "media_url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t50.2886-..."
},
```

The media url that returns is only the video. How can I get the video thumbnail for this too? Keep in mind this is a hashtag feed and not a users feed.

I have tried making a seperate call like using the id of the video

```
17850934621537158?fields=thumbnail_url
```

however, I am getting this error.

```
"error": {
"message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '17850934621537158' 
does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does 
not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
"type": "GraphMethodException",
"code": 100,
"error_subcode": 33,
"fbtrace_id": "AVB0L7jlmb2NCTIxTEXbWKD"
}
```

Can someone shed some light on this problem and a work around?

Comment: So you’re saying you can’t just add `thumbnail_url` to the field list of your original request?

Comment: @misorude That is correct, otherwise I get the same error as noted above.

Comment: That makes rather little sense, if you had the necessary rights to access the object ids in question before adding that field. Are you sure it is exactly the same error?

Comment: thumbnail_url is not an option when using recent_media https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/hashtag/recent-media#reading